# Javascript - Access an object

Tags: javascript, json, object, url, get

I pass an object of one page to another with GET method by URL like this:
`var url = "home-page?file="+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(file));`

In the page `home-page` that I open after the GET method, I receive the object on javascript:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

.
var file = getParameterByName('file');
```

like this:

> {"node":{"isLink":false,"isContainer":false,...

But I can't access to isLink value... I'm trying to do

> file.node.isLink

but this, not returns nothing.

Anyone know how can I access this?

Comment: `var obj = JSON.parse(file);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-parse the string as object with `JSON.parse()`:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(file);
```